# CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, alter

According to [this blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/create-or-alter-another-great-language-enhancement-in-sql-server-2016-sp1), `CREATE OR ALTER` feature was introduced in SQL Server 2016 SP1 but when I executed this statement for my SQL Server 2008 R2 version database, it worked. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you double check the connected SQL Server version? (SELECT @@VERSION)

Comment: Database version is SQL 2008 R2 and SQL Server version is SQL 2017. How can SQL server version affect this feature?

Comment: Checked again by installing SQL 2008 R2 SSMS and CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE is working fine. Database version is also SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: The version of SSMS doesn't matter - it's the server interpreting the commands.

Comment: Thanks Ben-Does that mean this will fail on SQL 2008 R2 SQL Server Instance or say till SQL 2014?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the comments established that the command was being run against SQL Server 2017 so nothing to see here

Answer (score 0):

You've got your database set at a COMPATIBILITY LEVEL for 2008 R2 attached to SQL Server 2017.  That compatibility level influences certain functionality, but does not affect whether or not the `CREATE OR ALTER` command works.

One key thing compatibility levels affect is the types of joins and optimisations SQL Server might perform.  That's because some of these may be undesirable until they've been evaluated, so Microsoft plays it safe by making them opt-in.  A great blog post is here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2023/04/what-does-setting-the-sql-server-compatibility-level-do/

Also note, just because you leave your database at compatibility level for 2008 R2, attached to 2017, does not mean that you take that database (its raw files, or a backup) and get it working in 2008 R2 again.